# What is the best way to intersect these two lists?

Tags: c#, collections, intersect

I have 2 lists in C#:

```
public class AvailableSlot
{
     public DateTime DateTime;
     public string Name
}

 List<AvailableSlot> list1 = GetList();
 List<AvailableSlot> list2 = GetAnotherList();
```

I want to call intersect on these lists to find out where there are items in both lists for the same date.  I know i can use .Intersect to get this info but I have a slightly more complicated requirement.  I want to return a intersected list but i want to this list to contain a list of objects with all of the name in them. so something like this:

```
  List<AvailableSlot2> intersectedList  . ..
```

where AvailableSlot2 is this below:

```
public class AvailableSlot2
{
     public DateTime DateTime;
     public string[] Names;
}
```

Is there any ability to do this transformation after trying to intersect between two lists?

Comment: are the `DateTime`s unique inside a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just union the two lists, group by DateTime and then pull out the names from the group:

```
var list1 = new List<AvailableSlot>
{
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), Name = "Alpha" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 2), Name = "Bravo" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 3), Name = "Charlie" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), Name = "Delta" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 2), Name = "Echo" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 3), Name = "Foxtrot" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 4), Name = "Golf" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 5), Name = "Hotel" }
};

var list2 = new List<AvailableSlot>
{
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), Name = "Apple" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 2), Name = "Bannana" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1), Name = "Dog" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 2), Name = "Egg" },
    new AvailableSlot { DateTime = new DateTime(2013, 2, 5), Name = "Hi" }
};

var list3 = list1.Where (l => list2.Where (li => l.DateTime == li.DateTime).Any ())
   .Union(list2.Where (l => list1.Where (li => l.DateTime == li.DateTime).Any ()));

var groupedItems = from slot in list3
    group slot by slot.DateTime into grp
    select new AvailableSlot2 {
        DateTime = grp.Key,
        Names = grp.Select (g => g.Name).ToArray()
    };

foreach(var g in groupedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.DateTime);
    foreach(var name in g.Names)
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
}
```

Output:

```
2/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
Alpha
Delta
Apple
Dog
---------------------
2/2/2013 12:00:00 AM
Bravo
Echo
Bannana
Egg
---------------------
2/5/2013 12:00:00 AM
Hotel
Hi
---------------------
```

Comment: for some reason i am still getting results in my final list that only existed in one of the lists (not both) . .still debugging

Comment: @leora, OK, added some code for a true intersection so that the DateTime must be in both lists. See the commented out code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LINQ to Objects `Join()` to line up items with the same DateTime property and then collect all the names into an array

```
var joinedItems = from slot1 in list1
                  join slot2 in list2
                  on slot1.DateTime equals slot2.DateTime into g
                  where g.Any()
                  select new AvailableSlot2
                  {
                      DateTime = slot1.DateTime,
                      Names = Enumerable.Range(slot1.Name,1).Union(g.Select(s => s.Name)).ToArray()
                  }
```

Comment: Enumerable.Range() seems to want 2 int arguments so this doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx):

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2013, 2, 1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2013, 3, 1);
DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(2013, 4, 1);

var list1 = new List<AvailableSlot>
{
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt1, Name = "n1",},
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt2, Name = "n2",},
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt1, Name = "n3",},
};

var list2 = new List<AvailableSlot>
{
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt1, Name = "n1",},
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt2, Name = "n2",},
    new AvailableSlot{DateTime = dt3, Name = "n3",},
};

var intersected = list1.Select (l => l.DateTime).
                        Intersect(list2.Select (l => l.DateTime));

var lookup = list1.Union(list2).ToLookup (
                                slot => slot.DateTime, slot => slot);

lookup.Where (l => intersected.Contains(l.Key)).Select (
    slot => new 
    {
        DateTime=slot.Key, 
        Names=slot.Select (s => s.Name)
    });
```

Which in this case gives the result:

```
DateTime            Names

01/02/2013 00:00    n1
                    n3
                    n1

01/03/2013 00:00    n2
                    n2
```

You could of course use Names=slot.Select(s => s.Name).Distinct() to get a distinct list of names.